# Using minted .Things are alright except List of Listing is small with * and in TOC the text is replaced by * instead of "List of Listings"

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, minted

[image: In table of content the text is replaced by * instead of "List of Listings"]

[image: List of listing is small with *]

[image: The code is printed correctly in text]

I am using listing and minted package already and code as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,final,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}

\listfiles
\fixpdflayout

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Computer Modern Typewritter (For bold ttfamily in listings)
\usepackage{lmodern}
% OR... Bera Mono
%\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} % TTT Font
%\usepackage{anyfontsize} % As the name says...

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% For Overleaf support
\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\useoverleaf{1}  % change to non-zero (for instance, 1) to enable it

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makecoverfile}[0]{%
  \immediate\write18{latexmk -pdf cover.tex}%
}
\makeatother

%For PDF merging
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%SET DPI to 300
\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1in/300\relax

\usepackage{morewrites} % Allow the use of a larger number of packages

%For English and Portuguese languages
%Portuguese will be the default.
%Use \setdefaultlanguage to change it
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}

% For custom date format
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{thesisdate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR} % Month Year

\usepackage{microtype} % Make pdf look better


% Uncomment to enable floats on facing pages
%\usepackage{dpfloat}

%Side by side figures
% Eg. Fig 1a, Fig 1b
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
%\let\tion\undefined
%\let\subfloat\undefined
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\RequirePackage{textcase}

% Dropped Caps
%\usepackage{lettrine}


% Configure Hyperlink color
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=false,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
% Or use the default
\usepackage{hyperref}

%Optional: Redefine section names
%\def\sectionautorefname{Section}
%\def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}
%\def\figureautorefname{Figure}
%\def\listingautorefname{Listing}
%\def\tableautorefname{Table}

%For PDF Comments
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{bookmark} % New Bookmarks

%For Multiple columns in Glossary
\usepackage{multicol}

%Math symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}

%Colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Euro symbol
\usepackage{eurosym}

% Code boxes
\ifthenelse{\equal{\useoverleaf}{0}}
{\usepackage[outputdir=build]{minted}}
{\usepackage{minted}}%

\renewcommand\listingscaption{Código}
\fvset{fontsize=\footnotesize} % Make Code blocks smaller than text

%Biber using IEEE style for proper UTF-8 support
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib/references.bib, bib/rfc.bib}

%Use acronyms
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} % For acronyms

% Enable chart support through pgf and tikz
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,trees,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,mindmap} % for pgf-umlsd

%For Electric Circuits
\usepackage[detect-weight=true, binary-units=true]{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = binary}

\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=.375}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/width=.3}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/height=.8}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/width=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=.7}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]

% For inline TT text (e.g. code snippets)
\usepackage{verbatim}

 %Frames around figures and allow force placement
\usepackage{float}

%Configure Float style
%\floatstyle{boxed}
%\restylefloat{table}
%\restylefloat{figure}
%\restylefloat{lstlisting}

%For test purposes
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Keep floats inside section!
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\let \oldsubsubsection \subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[2][]{
  \FloatBarrier
  \oldsubsubsection#1{#2}
}
\let \oldsubsection \subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[2][]{
  \FloatBarrier
  \oldsubsection#1{#2}
}
\let \oldsection \section
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{
  \FloatBarrier
  \oldsection#1{#2}
}
\let \oldchapter \chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2][]{
  \FloatBarrier
  \oldchapter#1{#2}
}


%%%% Use the built-in division styling
\headstyles{memman}

%%% ToC down to subsections
\settocdepth{subsection}

%%% Numbering down to subsections as well
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

%%%% extra index for first lines
\makeindex[lines]

%Margins for University of Aveiro Thesis
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

%Or custom spacing
%\addtolength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\useoverleaf}{0}}{}{\makecoverfile{}}%
\includepdf[pages=-]{cover.pdf}

%
%Front matter

%Custom Chapter style named thesis
\makechapterstyle{thesis}{% Based on ell
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily}
  \settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
    \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
    \hrulefill
    \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
    \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
    \hfill
    \raisebox{10mm}[0pt][0pt]{\fontsize{30}{25}\selectfont\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
                              \hspace*{1em}
    \end{adjustwidth}\vspace*{-3.0\onelineskip}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \vskip\onelineskip
    \raggedleft {\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak\vskip 4\onelineskip}}


%Select chapter style from existing or select custom
%\chapterstyle{thesis} % Others: dowding, demo2, dash, chappell, brotherton, bianchi, ger, madsen, tatcher, veelo,indexes)
% thesis can also be used as defined previously
%

%If you feel adventurous you can also define all aspects of your theme
%Use either this input or the chapterstyle before
%\input{custom-theme.tex}

\chapterstyle{veelo}
%Exclude sub figures from List of Figures
%\captionsetup[subfloat]{list=no}


% Texts
\newenvironment{introduction}
{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
   \itshape%
}
{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{2\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.2\baselineskip}%
}


%Select Page style
\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter

\tightlists
\midsloppy
\raggedbottom

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %subsections are added to the TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} %subsubsections are numbered


\cleardoublepage

%Table of contents
{\small\tableofcontents}
\cleardoublepage

%List of figures
{\small\listoffigures}

{\small\listoflistings}

%List of tables
\cleardoublepage
{\small\listoftables}

%Print Glossary
{\small\include{glossary}}

%
%Main document starts here
%
\mainmatter



% Start of Thesis text ----------------------------------------------------------
%Line spacing: 1.5 pt
\OnehalfSpacing

\include{chapters/chapter1}
%\include{chapter2}
%\include{chapter3}
%\include{chapter4}



% End of Thesis text ---------------------------------------------------------
% Including files is advised:


%Appendix

\backmatter


%Print all used references

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}

%Redefine References name
\defbibheading{bibliography}[Referências]{
    \chapter{#1}
}
\SingleSpacing
\setlength\bibitemsep{8pt}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\endgroup


%Load appendix
%\include{appendix-a}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please provide a complete example, also called an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), to help others to help you.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ   How  can I upload .tex file here?

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,final,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{minted}

\renewcommand\listingscaption{Código}
\fvset{fontsize=\footnotesize}\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter

\tightlists
\midsloppy
\raggedbottom

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 


\cleardoublepage

{\small\tableofcontents}
\cleardoublepage

{\small\listoffigures}
\cleardoublepage

{\small\listoflistings}

\cleardoublepage
{\small\listoftables}

\mainmatter

Comment: \begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{c}

#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
/* Block
 * comment */
 
int main()
{
    int i;
 
    // Line comment.
    puts("Hello world!");
 
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
    }
 
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{This is below the code.}
\label{lbl:snippet-test}
\end{listing}

Comment: You can edit the description of current question, then copy-and-paste the contents of tex file and markup them as code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues: first, the List of Listings is not automatically added to the Table of Contents in `memoir` (actually most standard documentclasses do not add the List of Listings). You can solve this by using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoflistingscaption}`.

Second, the redefinition of `\chapter` causes a problem because `minted` uses `\chapter*` for the list of listings, as explained and solved in the [answer by muzimuzhi Z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562911).

Third, `babel` doesn't provide a translation for List of Listings in Portuguese, so you need to set that explicitly using `\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption` (or alternatively `\addto\captionsportuguese{\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption` to set the translation only for Portuguese, but that is not really relevant in this case).

Putting everything together, minimized:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{placeins}

\renewcommand\listingscaption{Código}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{Lista de Códigos}

\let \oldchapter \chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand \chapter { s O{#3} m }{%
  \FloatBarrier
  \IfValueTF{#1}  % if optional star is seen
    {\oldchapter*{#3}}
    {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}
}

\begin{document}

%Table of contents
{\small\tableofcontents}
%List of figures
{\small\listoffigures}
%List of listings
{\small\listoflistings}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoflistingscaption}
%List of tables
{\small\listoftables}

\begin{figure}
\fbox{this is a figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{python}
print("this is a listing")
\end{minted}
\caption{A listing}
\end{listing}

\begin{table}
\fbox{this is a table}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The redefined `\chapter` does not accept an optional star `*`, hence caused the problem.

```
\let \oldchapter \chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2][]{
  \FloatBarrier
  \oldchapter#1{#2}
}
```

If `\chapter*{title}` is used, then `*` is recognized as `#2` and the `#1` is empty, hence it will expand to `\oldchapter{*} {title}` and producing the large `*` followed by small `List of Listings` output.

Use following redefinition instead

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand \chapter { s O{#3} m }{%
  \FloatBarrier
  \IfValueTF{#1}  % if optional star is seen
    {\oldchapter*{#3}}
    {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}
}
```

Similar modification should be done on `\section`.

Last but not least, your example won't compile without commenting out some lines.

Comment: Not working for me !